# Is this a correct derivation of completing the square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, completing-the-square

$x^2 + bx$

$=x^2 + bx + c - c$

$=(x + k)^2 - c$

$=x^2 + 2kx + (k^2 - c) = x^2 + bx + 0$

This implies:

$2k = b$, so $k = b/2$, and:

$k^2 - c = 0$, or $k^2 = c$, or $(b/2)^2 = c$

So to complete the square we are making the transformation:

$x^2 + bx \implies (x + b/2)^2 - (b/2)^2$

Comment: This is not correct, because you do not show where the $k$ comes from in the third line.  You have to prove that $k$ exists.

Comment: I would just start by defining $k$:  "Let $k = b/2$.  Then..."

Comment: @JairTaylor It's the intended goal is it not? We're trying to add/subtract some constant quantity to $x^2 + bx$ so we can change it into the form $(x+k)^2 - c$ by definition of the problem. Or is that not right?

Comment: Why are both $k$ and $c$ being made up out of no-where.  Don't invent things you don't need.  And define things *as* you need them-- don't "solve" them later.  Much simpler.  $x^2 + bx = x^2 + bx + (\frac b2)^2 - (\frac b2)^2 = (x + \frac b2)^2 - (\frac b2)^2$

Comment: @user51819 I don't know how the problem was stated to you.  But logically, you cannot write the symbol $k$ until you have defined what it means.  How would you know that this $k$ exists?

Comment: For example, it wouldn't make sense to write $x^2 + bx = a^x$ assuming this identity holds for all $x$.  In fact, there is no such constant $a$ in this case.

Comment: Instead, I would use what you've written here as scratch work to find what $k$ and $c$ ought to be, if they exist.  Once you have them, the derivation is just as simple as expanding out $(x + b/2)^2 - (b/2)^2$ and seeing that it is $x^2 + bx$.

Comment: @fleablood But that's exactly what I'm doing. In order to solve the problem it has to be defined first. IMO pulling $b/2$ out of thin air is a way to solve the problem but is not part of the problem's definition.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are asking.  Completing the square is a straight forward procedure that once you do it is completely mundane.  $(x + k)^2 = x^2 + 2kx + k^2$ so if you have $x^2 + bx$ and you want to complete the square the summand will have to be $\frac b2$ and you must add and subtract $\frac {b^2} 4$.  What exactly are you *asking*?

Comment: @fleablood It is straightforward and mundane to a professional mathematician, but perhaps not to a student doing precalculus.

Comment: My issue is why you through in a c-c.  That's done with no motivation.  You want $x^2 + bx = (x + k)^2 +d $ for some $k$ and some $d$.  As $(x+k)^2  d = x^2 + 2kx + k^2+d$ we have $k = \frac b2$ and $k^2 + d = 0$ so $d=-\frac {b^2}4$.  The $c$ without motivation is just weird.

Comment: I think there’s much ado about nothing, going on. This is a good way to figure out how completing the square works. Sure, a few additional words could help somebody else follow your train of thought more closely, but ... if it’s to help you understand completing the square, then it appears to be working perfectly well.

Comment: @user51819 Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is just fine. This is often how mathematics is done; in the initial stages, you may run into a dead end or use unnecessary variables. Later on, once you have found that $k$ does exist and equals $b/2$, you can rework your exposition to avoid $k$ entirely and just use $b/2$. You will often see proofs in textbooks where the author "magically" knows what substitutions to use, etc.; this comes from experience and from working through the problem as you have done, then presenting it as if it were obvious all along.

That said, there's a circularity in your first few lines that is confusing and should be avoided. You wrote:

> $$\begin{align}
> x^2+bx &= x^2+bx+c−c\\
> &=(x+k)^2−c\\
> &=x^2+2kx+(k^2−c)\\
> &=x^2+bx+0
> \end{align}$$

It's strange to begin and end with $x^2+bx$, since it isn't clear where you're going. Instead, leave off that last line, thus:

> $$\begin{align}
> x^2+bx &= x^2+bx+c−c\\
> &=(x+k)^2−c\\
> &=x^2+2kx+(k^2−c)
> \end{align}$$
>   for some $k$. Equating coefficients, we have $2k=b$ and $k^2-c=0$. [etc.]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct, indeed

$$(x + b/2)^2 - (b/2)^2=x^2+bx+\frac{b^2}4-\frac{b^2}4-=x^2+bx$$

Answer (score 0):

It's true, but you can get it much  more easier:
$$x^2+bx=x^2+bx+\frac{b^2}{4}-\frac{b^2}{4}=\left(x+\frac{b}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^2$$

Comment: Yes but I think my issue with this approach is knowing ahead of time where the $b^2/4$ is coming from, I am trying to pretend that I do not know / deriving it from scratch a little more formally.

Comment: But you can use $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$. I think it's simple. $x^2+bx=x^2+2\cdot x\cdot(.)$ and easy to see that $(.)=\frac{b}{2}.$

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  You are trying to derive.

As you want to derive $x^2 + bx = (x + k)^2 + c$ I'd *start* with that line:

"we want $x^2 + bx = (x+k)^2 +c$ and we need to find the $c$ and $k$ that will make it so.

You started instead with

$x^2 + bx = x^2 + bx + c - c = (x+k)^2 -c$ with, I guess (????) then assumption that $(x+k)^2 = x^2 + bx + c$.  But without any reason I don't get what you are doing.  What is that $c$.  It just came out of nowhere.  Why do you think that $x + bx + c = (x + k)^2$ where did the $k$ come from?  What *are* you doing?

It doesnt seem clear.

As you want to solve $x^2 + bx = (x + k)^2 -c$ then *start* there.  It's almost as though you are afraid to ask the *right* question so you ask the *wrong* question $x^2 + bx + c -c = (x + k)^2 - c$.

But if you say:

"$x^2 + bx = (x+k)^2 -c $; what are the $k$ and $c$ we need to make the happen?"

The solution is clear.

$(x+k)^2 - c = x^2 + 2kx + k^2 -c$ and we want $x^2 + bx = x^2 + 2kx +k^2 - c$ so $k = \frac b2$ and $k^2 - c = \frac {b^2}4 - c = 0$.  So $c = -\frac {b^2}4$.